# Add new column in Pyspark dataframe based on where condition on other column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark data frame as follows:

```
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
|package_id  | location    | package_scan_code  | 
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
|123         | Denver      |05                  |  
|123         | LosAngeles  |03                  |  
|123         | Dallas      |09                  |  
|123         | Vail        |02                  | 
|456         | Jacksonville|05                  |  
|456         | Nashville   |09                  |
|456         | Memphis     |03                  |
```

"package_scan_code" 03 represents the origin of the package.

I want to add a column "origin" to this dataframe such that for each package (identified by "package_id"), the values in the newly added origin column would be the same location that corresponds to "package_scan_code" 03.

In the above case, there are two unique packages 123 and 456, and they have origins as LosAngeles and Memphis respectively (corresponding to package_scan_code 03).

So I want my output to be as follows:

```
+------------+-------------+--------------------+------------+
| package_id |location     | package_scan_code  |origin      |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+------------+
|123         | Denver      |05                  | LosAngeles |
|123         | LosAngeles  |03                  | LosAngeles |
|123         | Dallas      |09                  | LosAngeles |
|123         | Vail        |02                  | LosAngeles |
|456         | Jacksonville|05                  |  Memphis   |
|456         | Nashville   |09                  |  Memphis   |
|456         | Memphis     |03                  |  Memphis   |
```

How can I achieve this in Pyspark? I tried `.withColumn`   method, but I could not get the condition right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the data frame by `package_scan_code == '03'` and then join back with the original data frame:

```
(df.filter(df.package_scan_code == '03')
   .selectExpr('package_id', 'location as origin')
   .join(df, ['package_id'], how='right')
   .show())
+----------+----------+------------+-----------------+
|package_id|    origin|    location|package_scan_code|
+----------+----------+------------+-----------------+
|       123|LosAngeles|      Denver|               05|
|       123|LosAngeles|  LosAngeles|               03|
|       123|LosAngeles|      Dallas|               09|
|       123|LosAngeles|        Vail|               02|
|       456|   Memphis|Jacksonville|               05|
|       456|   Memphis|   Nashville|               09|
|       456|   Memphis|     Memphis|               03|
+----------+----------+------------+-----------------+
```

Note: this assumes you have at most one `package_scan_code` equal to `03` per `package_id`, otherwise the logic wouldn't be correct and you need to rethink how `origin` should be defined.

Comment: You approached it in the simplest way. Nice one.

Comment: @Psidom I am getting an error saying: `AnalysisException: u'Cannot resolve column name "package_id" among (_col0, _col2,....);' ` I tried printing out the schema and the column names display correctly, I also tried removing white spaces using trim function but none of them resolves the problem

Comment: So you can't even do `df.select('package_id')`?

Comment: I can do a select. It's the join statement that's failing. It seems very weird.

Comment: I fixed the issue. There seems to be some kind of bug in Spark or Pyspark, and I had to rename column names using `alias`. So the statement became `(df.filter(df.package_scan_code == '03')
   .select(col('package_id').alias('package_id'), col('location').alias('origin'))
   .join(df, ['package_id'], how='right')
   .show())`. This worked!

Answer (score 0):

This code should work irrespective of how many times the `package_scan_code=03` occurs for each `package_id` in the dataframe. I have added one more  `(123,'LosAngeles','03')` to demonstrate that -

**Step1:** Creating the DataFrame

```
values = [(123,'Denver','05'),(123,'LosAngeles','03'),(123,'Dallas','09'),(123,'Vail','02'),(123,'LosAngeles','03'),
          (456,'Jacksonville','05'),(456,'Nashville','09'),(456,'Memphis','03')]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['package_id','location','package_scan_code'])
```

**Step 2:** Creating a dictionary of `package_id` and `location`.

```
df_count = df.where(col('package_scan_code')=='03').groupby('package_id','location').count()
dict_location_scan_code = dict(df_count.rdd.map(lambda x: (x['package_id'], x['location'])).collect())
print(dict_location_scan_code)
    {456: 'Memphis', 123: 'LosAngeles'}
```

**Step 3:** Creating a column, mapping the dictionary.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, create_map, lit
from itertools import chain
mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*dict_location_scan_code.items())])
df = df.withColumn('origin', mapping_expr.getItem(col('package_id')))
df.show()
+----------+------------+-----------------+----------+
|package_id|    location|package_scan_code|    origin|
+----------+------------+-----------------+----------+
|       123|      Denver|               05|LosAngeles|
|       123|  LosAngeles|               03|LosAngeles|
|       123|      Dallas|               09|LosAngeles|
|       123|        Vail|               02|LosAngeles|
|       123|  LosAngeles|               03|LosAngeles|
|       456|Jacksonville|               05|   Memphis|
|       456|   Nashville|               09|   Memphis|
|       456|     Memphis|               03|   Memphis|
+----------+------------+-----------------+----------+
```

Comment: The step "Step 2: Creating a dictionary of package_id and location." moves data to the driver which is very dangerous for large datasets and may take quite some time. Why don't you do a simple join (given your `withColumn` with the `mapping_expr`)?

Comment: Notwithstanding your desire to educate and help Jacek, thanks for the negative vote. Deeply appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your solution @cph_sto. As I commented on @Psidom's solution, there was a bug that required me to rename columns using `alias`. After renaming, your solution would have worked too. His was just a simpler approach.

Comment: PreethiS Sure, proceed with what you perceive as best suited to your needs. Cordially,

Comment: @cph_sto, I have a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62318004/pyspark-dealing-w-dict-with-no-values